# uniqueInstance on Seaside Smalltalk

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, smalltalk, seaside

I'm trying to implement the Singleton pattern on Seaside. 
Here is my code:

```
        uniqueInstance
            uniqueInstance ifNil: [ uniqueInstance := self createInstance].
            ^ uniqueInstance

    createInstance
        ^ self basicNew

initialize
    users:= OrderedCollection new.
```

On the instance side I have *users* that is the instance variable. When I call Application uniqueInstance initialize works. When I inspect the users variable, it said "Identity Set" instead of an OrderedCollection.

Can anybody give me a solution to my mistake?

Comment: Are there any other methods that assign `users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a (Pharo) mailing list discussion regarding singletons I wrote about some variations some time ago https://www.peteruhnak.com/blog/2015/12/06/singleton-variations/ .

But the gist of the singleton is:

1. (usually) block `MyThing class>>new`

   - because it is a singleton
2. call `super new` or `self basicNew initialize` when creating the instance

   - this is to go around the blocked `new`; if your dialect doesn't call `initialize` automatically then use the latter form
3. (optionally) add `MyThing class>>reset` to `nil` the instance

   - for convenience mostly (with `<script: 'self reset'>` pragma can be made even better)

So in your case it can be something like this:

```
Users class>>uniqueInstance
    ^ uniqueInstance ifNil: [ uniqueInstance := super new ]

Users class>>new
    self error: 'Users is a singleton -- send uniqueInstance instead'

Users>>initialize
    users:= OrderedCollection new
```

And if you are in Pharo, feel free the explore the existing implementations

```
MessageBrowser browse: (#uniqueInstance implementors select: #isMetaSide).
MessageBrowser browse: (#default implementors select: #isMetaSide).
MessageBrowser browse: (#current implementors select: #isMetaSide).
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `#createInstance` method sends the `#basicNew` message, but this one doesn't send `#initialize`. So nobody is initializing your object and `users` remains `nil`. There must be some lazy method that sets `users` to an `IndentitySet` and that's why you get that. But no one is making it an `OrderedCollection`.

To `initialize` the instance use `#new` instead of `#basicNew`; at least in Pharo and some other dialects `#new` will send `#initialize` for you.

Comment: So where shoud I call the initialize method?

Comment: @LuchoLaFrazia Please notice that I've completed the answer.

Comment: Please see also @Peter's answer. In your case I would implement `createInstance` as `^self basicNew initialize` rather than as `^super new` because many people (including myself) prefer not to use `super` with a different selector.